# Using the RSA system...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Using the RSA system with $(m,e)=(51,5)$ find a $d\ge1$ that will decode the messages.

What I have so far (not sure if this is right):

Since, $m=51$ and $e=5$ then the $\gcd(51,5)=1$ then:
$$5d \equiv 1\pmod{51}$$
$$5d\equiv 55\pmod{51}$$
$$d=11$$

Comment: If I remember RSA correctly, what you want is not $de\equiv 1\bmod m$, but $de\equiv 1\bmod \varphi(m)$ where $\varphi$ is the totient function. It is $\varphi(m)$ that is hard to compute for large $m$.

Comment: Then $d=13$, because $5d \equiv 1\pmod{32}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters: it is more common to call the public key $(n, e)$ rather than $(m, e)$, since $m$ is often used for the *message* to be encrypted rather than for the product of the primes $p$ and $q$.

Either way, $d \equiv e^{-1} \pmod{\varphi({n})}$, which means that $d \cdot e \equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi({n})}$.

We see that $ \varphi({n}) = 32$, so we are left to solve $5 \cdot d \equiv 1 \pmod{32}$, which would mean that $d = 13$ (solvable using Euclid's extended gcd algorithm).

When using RSA in practise, n would be sufficiently large, making $\varphi({n})$ infeasible to compute.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this.  "Randomly choose" the message be $15$.  Then the encrypted message is $15^5 \pmod {51}=36$.  If you are right, $36^{13} \pmod {51}$ should equal $15$, which it does.